# Is there an easy way to get all global variables defined in a Lua code file?

Tags: lua, global-variables

Everybody knows that variables in Lua, if not explicitly defined as "local", will be global. This will sometimes cause problems, like overriding library functions, or unexpectedly providing a value for another global variable with the same name. So it should be very helpful if there's a way to find all global variables that is defined in a single Lua code file.

However, I failed to find any clue on this seemingly quite-popular problem. The best answer I can get online is using _G to print all global variables in the environment, which isn't of much help. I'm currently coding Lua in Intellij Idea with Emmylua, a powerful tool that can show global variables in a special style, and it can easily trace a global variable to its definition; but when the code becomes quite long, this will not help much either.

So basically, I just want to get a list of global variables defined in a given Lua code file. Either with a tool or with a wonderful function. If it can make things easier, we may presume the code file is a module. If it can further print the definition locations for these global variables, that's even better. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `lua show_globals.lua < your_script.lua` The tool is [here](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/e4ab3bfc777faf4482a1b3f3ae19181b)

Comment: See also http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-12/msg00397.html

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you so much, sir! It really works so well! There's a small flaw, though, because when I tested this, it said "print" is a global variable, but I merely used it, didn't define it. Hope there's some way to fix it.

Comment: @lhf That seems much easier to follow, but how am I supposed to use it? I'm using Windows system now.

Comment: Try luacheck, that will tell you when you are setting something you shouldn't

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - `show_globals.lua` is updated to distinguish between read and write access.  To display only write access to globals and skip all read access, run it this way: `lua show_globals.lua W < your_script.lua`.

Comment: Lua 5.2 and later, or earlier? `print(_VERSION)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you soooo much and it really helped me a lot! Only one more question: if I want to filter out the global functions, which parts should I modify? Seems the filed lexem.type is the right way, but its content isn't much as I had expected...

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - Syntax analysis is unable to always determine type of Lua values.  For example, `func = create_new_func()`  How to deduce type of value of global variable `func`?

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - To filter out most obvious global function definitions comment out lines 1001-1004.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That' really helpful! Thanks a lot! But now I find that getting the read accesses of global variables (excluding global function calls) quite useful because sometimes I carelessly reference global variables that don't exist at all. So the problem is to recognizing global function references. I know this is even more difficult than figuring out global function definitions, but I really appreciate it if this can be done. For me, I think figuring out the names followed by parenthesis will be enough. So is there an easy way to accomplish this? Many thanks!

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - To ignore global function invocations replace function "read_prefixexp" (lines 699-860) with [this one](https://pastebin.com/gXfcGdDD)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you so much for your hard work and patience! One last question: could I use your code in our project for developing purposes only?

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - Yes, MIT license.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Aha! I've tried the newest edition and it works so fine! Thank you so much, buddy!

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod - Nothing was changed in the latest edition :-)  Just appended the license text.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Hi, buddy! I've found a small problem: I've commented out the four lines in function read_namelist, but it will still print out global function definitions of this form:

FuncA = function() return 241 end

So is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, assignments are not analyzed, only definitions like `function x() end` are filtered out.  But why do you want to search for `x = something` but don't want `x = function() end`?  I don't understand how this might be useful?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Haha, just different coding habits among my workmates.

Answer (score 2):

Lua doesn't have a way to tell when or where a global was introduced.

In the special that the value is a function, `debug.getinfo` may be able to help by telling you where the function is defined (which is often but not always the same place where the function is made global).

You can capture the needed information at the time the global is introduced. This can be done by setting a metatable with a `__newindex` method on the global table. This method will be called when a new global is introduced (but not when an existing global is overridden). In this method, you can figure out where the caller came from with `debug.getinfo`. Also beware, if any of your other code is trying to use a metatable on the global environment, you must play nicely with it. (It can only have one metatable.)

You can also avoid using the global table. One in-between way of doing this is to override the environment. In Lua 5.2 and Lua 5.3, this is done by declaring a local table called `_ENV` -- all accesses to the global table will instead access this table. (Actually, global accesses always use `_ENV` and `_ENV` is `_G` by default.) You can make this mostly invisible by giving this `_ENV` a metatable that forwards accesses to `_G` (or whatever other environment). The difference here is that `__newindex` will still be called even if a binding exists in `_G`, so this method can detect overrides.

Using `_ENV`, though is inherently local to a scope (e.g. each file needs to override it). Such a hook could be installed globally as well though. If you load your modules manually with the `load` function (unlikely), you can just supply a custom `_ENV` as an argument. If you use `require`, it is possible to get a hold of the loaded file before it is executed by overriding (or monkey patching) the Lua searcher in `package.searchers[2]`. This is the built-in function that `require` calls to find the file in your filesystem and then load it. The return value is the loaded function which `require` then runs. So, after it is loaded but before it is returned back to `require`, you could use `debug.setupvalue` to override the default `_ENV` value (if any).

Example code (only lightly tested):

```
local global_info = {}

local default_searcher2 = package.searchers[2]

package.searchers[2] = function(...)
  local result = default_searcher2(...)
  local parent_environment = _G
  local my_env = setmetatable({}, {
    __index = parent_environment,
    __newindex = function(self, k, v)
      local new_info = debug.getinfo(2)

      -- keeping rich data like this could be a memory leak
      -- if some globals are assigned repeatedly, but that
      -- may still be okay in a debugging scenario
      local history = global_info[k]
      if history == nil then
        history = {}
        global_info[k] = history
      end
      table.insert(history, {info = new_info, value = v})

      parent_environment[k] = v
    end,
  })
  if type(result) == "function" then
    debug.setupvalue(result, 1, my_env)
  end
  return result
end

function gethistory(name)
  local history = global_info[name]
  if history == nil then
    print('"' .. name .. '" has never been defined...')
  else
    print('History for "' .. name .. '":')
    for _, record in ipairs(history) do
      print(record.info.short_src .. ": " .. record.info.currentline)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the hook here will only apply to files required after this code has been run, and basically only applies to Lua files (not C libs) that get included via the built-in `require`. It doesn't set a metatable on the global environment, so not conflict there, but it could be circumvented if files access `_G` directly (or e.g. setup access to `_G` instead of `_ENV` in their own `_ENV` tables). Such things can also be accounted for, but it can be a rabbit hole depending on how "invisible" you need this patch to be.

In Lua 5.1, instead of `_ENV`, you have `setfenv` which I believe can be used to similar effect.

Also note that all the methods I'm outlining can only detect global accesses that actually get executed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Local versus global is a binding issue, which is primarily established at compile-time. Setting a variable is, of course, well-determined at compile-time.

Lua provides the `luac` compiler, which takes the argument `-l` for list.

In Lua 5.1, there is the opcode `SETGLOBAL`. A column indicates the line number of the statement and the comment indicates the name of the global.

In 5.2 and later, there is the opcode `SETTABUP`. A column indicates the line number of the statement and the comment indicates the name of the table and key. "Globals" are in the table referenced by the `_ENV` upvalue.

So, you can easily find the line number of any statement that sets a global variable with the tools Lua provides.

BTW—under many module systems, a module script would not set any global variables.